# NFT collection Markt

Tags: nft

I want to create my own collection with my original NFT designs

I want to create my own collection with my original NFT designs
but I couldn't find the field or tab to create the collection

Comment: Question is not clear. Where are you trying to create the NFT collection? On any existing marketplaces?